# complex mysql query join with in tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a task that deals with complex JOIN query.

**Tabel 1: object_category** (Tree like structure to have parent category to child category hierarchy)

```
----------------------
category_id parent_id
----------------------
1           null
2           null
3           1
4           1
5           2
6           2
----------------------
```

Note category 3 is a child of 1, 5 is child of 2, etc....

**Table 2: object_category_map** (table to map object_id with category_id of object_category table)

```
----------------------
object_id  category_id
----------------------
23          1
23          4
23          6
24          2
24          5
----------------------
```

The task is to find the object_id which have do not have parent_id mapped for the  category_id.

**Example1:**
object_id: 24, category_id : 2, 5
in Table 2, object_id 24 has category_id 5 associated and also parent_id of 5 it is 2,

**Example2:**
object_id: 23, category_id : 1, 4, 6
object_id 23 miss parent_id(2) for the category_id 6.

Task is to find 23 that is list of object_id(s) form the table2 which are situation like 23.

kindly help solving this. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, what you are trying to achieve is a node hierarchy concept, here you can make use of JOINs at a fixed level, say parent's level are upto 2 so you can make upto 3 joins, but what if the hierarchy of parent's keep on increasing? So for this you will have to traverse back the node hierarchy until you get parent_id as NULL.
For doing this you require programming efforts + SQL query efforts and make use of recursive function until you receive the parent_id as NULL. What language are you using so I can point out right example

Comment: I'm using PHP with Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this.

```
select object_parent_needed.object_id
from (
    select object_id,object_category_map.category_id,parent_id
    from object_category_map 
    join object_category on object_category_map.categor_id = object_category.category_id
    where parent_id is not null
) object_parent_needed
left outer join object_category_map on object_category_map.object_id = object_parent_needed.object_id  
                                    and object_category_map.category_id = object_parent_needed.parent_id
where object_category_map.category_id is null
```